# Navigation.PushModalAsync not working while given inside a Tapgesture in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
var tapGestureRecognizer1 = new TapGestureRecognizer();

sub_header.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer1);

tapGestureRecognizer1.Tapped += (s, e) =>
{
                             Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DisplayContent());
};
```

Here sub_header is a label and tap gesture is give to that. While debugging the control is going to 'DisplayContent' page but the view is still within the same page. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below

```
var tapGestureRecognizer1 = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer1.Tapped += (s, e) =>
                  {
                      Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DisplayContent());
                  };

sub_header.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer1);
```

Comment: use await with PushModalAsync